# How to get a list of valid values for a CSS property with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to get a list of valid values for a given CSS property with Javascript or check if the value you set is valid?

Ex.: If I try to set `document.getElementById('foo').style.cursor = "grab";`.

Nothing happens and the property remains unchanged(at least in chrome).

I'd like to get a list of valid values for the current browser only.

For example, on Firefox I'd get `-moz-grab` in the list and on IE I wouldn't get grab or any of it's variants.

I want to be able to add vendor prefixes when needed and maybe have a way to provide a fallback.

Comment: `text-align` can take only `left, right, center, justify, start`. `bar` is invalid for `text-align`

Comment: You mean detect appended `Maincontent_` etc. to your control?

Comment: I don't know what ``Maincontent_`` is, I googled it to no avail.

Comment: There is no easy way.

Comment: At the very least, the developer tools in Firefox and Chrome show that they do store a list of supported keyword values somewhere internally. However, whether you can access that list of values is another story...

Comment: @BoltClock Isn't the list of supported keyword values derived from the user-agent API? i.e., not defined in JavaScript http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#supported-css-property

Comment: @Quantastical: Exactly that. I highly doubt this API can be accessed in user code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know your question is asking for a way to check valid values for vendor specific cursors (and, potentially, other CSS properties), but if all you are looking for is a cross-browser solution for styling cursors, you might just want to use your own images for the cursors in question.

http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur
http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur

For example, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.cursor = "url(/closedhand.cur) 4 4";
```

You might even wish to use this in conjunction with a check to see if known properties are valid, for example:

```
if( window.CSS.supports('cursor','grab') )
{
  cursor = 'grab';
}
else if( window.CSS.supports('cursor', '-moz-grab') )
{
  cursor = '-moz-grab';
}
else
{
  cursor = 'url(/grab.cur)';
}
document.getElementById('foo').style.cursor = cursor;
```

You could easily extend this to test all of the popular vendor prefixes, then only apply this logic to the properties with which you know have limited browser support.

[CSS.supports API Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=css.supports)
[CSS.supports MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)

Comment: the ``CSS.supports`` method is what I was looking for, just a shame it isn't widely supported. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Erik: `CSS.supports()` doesn't give you a list of supported values - it tests a property-value combination that you have to supply yourself. Except the premise of your original question is that you *don't know* these values in advance.

Comment: I didn't put it in the title, but from the beginning I asked if there was a way to check if a value was valid. It seems like there isn't any regular way to get the list of possible values. This answer kinda works for me cause I can use ``CSS,suports()`` when it is available and use a fallback when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that comes to my mind is to pre-populate arrays with the valid css values, and then search -

```
var validValues = {
    'textAlign': ['left', 'right', 'center', 'justify', 'start']
};

var userSpecifiedCSSValue = documet.getElementById('foo').style.textAlign.toLower();
if (validValues.textAlign.indexOf(userSpecifiedCSSValue) > -1) {
    // valid
}
```

Note: `indexOf` is not available for IE <= 8.

If you want to make it generic -

```
var userStyle = document.getElementById('foo').style,
    userSpecifiedValue,
    allowedCSSValues;

for (cssProperty in userStyle) {

    if (userStyle.hasOwnProperty(cssProperty) && 
            validValues.hasOwnProperty(cssProperty)) {

        userSpecifiedValue = userStyle[cssProperty].toLower();
        allowedCSSValues = validValues[cssProperty]

        if (allowedCSSValues.indexOf(userSpecifiedValue) > -1) {
            // valid
        } else {
            // invalid
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want to include browser-specific validation, then you can create list of valid values based on the browser type. Just create another layer in your object -

```
var validValues = {
    'chrome': {
        'textAlign': []// arrays with values
    }
}
```

However to me this still seems like a hacky solution.

Comment: I can't hardcode the list of valid values as it changes depending on the browser used.

Comment: @Erik: You can list all the browser-specific allowed values, and then get the right one based on browser detection. As far as I know, there is no option in JavaScript which will automatically give you the allowed values for a certain css property.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to look up the validity of a CSS property's value in JavaScript, without using a library that maintains a list of validation logic.

If you don't want to write your own, you could potentially include the [CSSLint GitHub](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint) with your project, since that is exactly what they are doing.